# SQL SERVER - Change column value if value exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, view, sql-update

I have the following problem.
Imagine I get the following return table from a select statement

```
Column A   Column B
100        aaa
100        bbb
100        ccc
200        ddd
300        eee
```

So the question is, how can I change my SQL Select statement to add a new column that shows the numbers of times the Column A has a repeat value. The problem is that I need to get some subgrups with an order.

For example, it should return something like:

```
  Column A   Column B  Column C
    100        aaa     1
    100        bbb     2
    100        ccc     3
    200        ddd     1
    300        eee     1
```

Thank you very much for your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the classic usecase for the analytic `RANK()` function:

```
SELECT a, b, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY b) AS c
FROM   my_table
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. That is what I needed. The only problem is that the information is in a database of SQL SERVER 2000, so this function doesnt work. I try to use the same information via linked server with SQL SERVER 2012, but it didnt work. Is it a way to use this RANK() function in SQL 2000 (or a similar function) or use this function via linked server?

Answer (score 2):

Add `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColA ORDER BY SomethingElse) as ColC`. That gives you a sequential row number per "group" in ColA.

Comment: Thank you for your support. That is what I needed. The only problem is that the information is in a database of SQL SERVER 2000, so this function doesnt work. I try to use the same information of the original database via linked server using a SQL SERVER 2012, but it didnt work. Is it a way to use this function (or a similar function) in SQL 2000  or use this function via linked server?